# Mac Utility doesn't show any disk in Recovery Mode

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

After booting my Mac it used to hang either immediately or after some time, so I put my OS on update. As usual, it asked me to restart so I did, but now it keeps on saying:

> "The installer resources were not found. Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again"

So I started my system in Recovery M and went to Disk Utility,1 but it doesn't show any disk.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Sorry to hear you are having trouble updating your Mac. Disk Utility not showing any disks is not good. What is the model of your Mac and which version of macOS is installed on your Mac? Depending on the model, you could replace the hard disk/have your hard disk replaced.

Comment: The Mac or OS "hanging" at random times is classic symptoms of a failing hard drive. Something to keep in mind for the future. I hope you have a backup. If you have not ever worked inside your Mac (EG opened and poked around) it is likely that the HD/SSD has failed. If you **have** opened it up and poked around it is possible something has come loose and/or disconnected. Ignoring the possibility you have opened it up it may be time to replace the HD/SSD.